# Group satisfying the maximal (minimal) condition for normal subgroups but not satisfying the maximal (minimal) condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group, infinite-groups

It is trivial to show that if a group $G$ satisfies the maximal condition on subgroups (denoted by $Max$), then $G$ satisfies the maximal condition on its normal subgroups (denoted by $Max-n$). We have a similar statement for the minimal condition ($Min$) and the minimal condition on normal subgroups ($Min-n$).

We claim that the inverse is not true, we have to find an example. In my course we got the following examples:

1. Example of group $G$ such that $G \in Max-n$ and $G \notin Max$:
   Let $p$ prime number and
   $$A = \left\lbrace \frac{m}{p^n} : m \in \mathbb{Z}, \ n \in \mathbb{N}_0 \right\rbrace.$$
   Let
   $$x: a \in A \mapsto p a \in A ,$$
   then $x\in\operatorname{Aut}A$, let $G = \langle x \rangle \ltimes A$.

I have a proof that $G \in Max-n$, but why $G \notin Max$?

2. Example of group $G$ such that $G \in Min-n$ and $G \notin Min$:
   Let $p$ prime number, let $F$ algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Let $q \neq p$ prime number and $H \leq \bigl( F \setminus \{0\}, \cdot \bigr)$ such that $H \cong Z(q^\infty)$ (there's a proposition that tells me such $q$ exists). Let $A$ the subfield of $F$ generated by $H$, then
   $$A = \lbrace n_1 h_1 + \cdots + n_t h_t : n_1, \dots, n_t \in \mathbb{Z}, \ h_1, \dots, h_t \in H \rbrace .$$
   For all $h \in H$, let
   $$\theta(h): a \in A \mapsto h a \in A ,$$
   we have $\theta(h)\in\operatorname{Aut}\bigl(A, +\bigr)$. Let
   $$\theta: h \in H \mapsto \theta(h) \in\operatorname{Aut}\bigl(A, +\bigr) ,$$
   it is an homomorfism. Let $(G, \cdot) = (H, \cdot) \ltimes_\theta (A, +)$.

I have a proof that $G \in Min-n$, but why $G \notin Min$?

*Note:* $Z(q^\infty)$ is the Prufer q-group

**EXTRA:** do you have any other (simpler) example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
1)\ \langle1\rangle<\langle1/p\rangle<\langle1/p^2\rangle<\ldots
$$

$2)$ Pick $t_k\in H$ such that $|t_k|=q^k$. We have
$$
\langle t_1,t_2,t_3,\ldots\rangle>
\langle t_2,t_3,\ldots\rangle>
\langle t_3,\ldots\rangle>\ldots
$$